# How to style only the text of a div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with an image and text. I only want to style the text from this div. With an image you can only style the image with `.content img{ }`, can you do this with text as well?

```
<div class="footer">
   <div class="telefoon"><img src="images/media/telefoon.png" width="30">06-123456</div>
   <div class="mail"><img src="images/media/mail.png" width="30">example@gmail.com</div>
   <a class="instagram" href=https://www.instagram.com/example/><img src="images/media/instagram.png" width="30">@example</a>
</div>
```

In this case I want the text to have `margin-bottom: 15px;` and the images not.

Or when someone has a different solution for the whole problem because basically my telephone, mail and instagram information is at the bottom of the icon instead of the middle.

Comment: Just use `.content { }` and set whatever text styling you need there.

Comment: You can do this. The best way to do it is wrap your text in a `<p>` tag, `<h1>` tag, or something similar and replace `img` with whatever tag you use. Example: `.content p { color: red; }`

Comment: Building on what dvo said-- you can also wrap it w/ a classed `<span>` which you can use to give it styling but won't imbue it with any inherent semantic meaning or default browser styles.

Comment: But I also have an ```a``` with an image and text, how do I only style the text then?

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please so that we can see the exact issue

Comment: Just curious, but why are the first two (telefoon & mail) wrapped in divs but the third (instagram) isn't? Consistency is helpful; the third could be `<div class="instagram"><a ... href ...>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to style your text, insert your text in a p tag for example and with the css use .content p {}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no block element around the text (e.g. p, span, h1-h6, etc), [try using :not for the image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) - although I don't see how the img would inherit any typography styling

Answer (score 0):

Add a span tag for the text and style the  span tag that shd solve your problem